# How to use UITableView to display 2 UILabels and a grid of images, also auto update the Cell height

Tags: ios, uitableview

I need to build a `UITableView` to display a list of posts, and each post will contain 3 sections.

1. Title (UILabel with 1 line of text)
2. Content (UILabel with multi lines of texts)
3. Grid of Images (number of images will vary from each row)

I have followed [this post](http://derpturkey.com/autosize-uitableviewcell-height-programmatically/).

I am able to add the Title and Content, and with autolayout it works as I need it to. However, I cannot add the grid of images.

I have create a custom cell view class just like `AutoSizeCell.h/AutoSizeCell.m` in the above post. Also I have created a modal class to have three properties (title, content and `NSMutableArray` of image names I need to display in the grid) However, it seems I cannot pass the images names to `AutoSizeCell.m`, so I cannot display the image grid.

```
@implementation AutoSizeCellContents

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

controller:

```
-(void)configureCell:(AutoSizeCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Configure the cell for this indexPath
    cell.category.text = [self getCategoryAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.pastTense.text = [self getPastTenseAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    for (NSString *imageName in [self getImagesAtIndexPath:indexPath]) {
        NSLog(@"image name %@",imageName);
        [cell.images addObject:@"hellp"];
    }

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Create a reusable cell
    AutoSizeCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"plerp"];
    if(!cell) {
        cell = [[AutoSizeCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"plerp"];
        [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You should show your code (the relevant part). Without it's like poking in the mist.

Comment: well, I am wondering if anyone could point the direction how would they solve this problem.

Comment: You did not read/understand my first comment. Nobody at SO is clairvoyant. Please provide your code. Else you will not get help here.

Comment: @ThomasKilian, really Appreciate for your help, and here is the link to my code https://github.com/ankermarco/AutoSizingTable

Comment: You can see in AutoSizingController.h -(void)configureCell:(AutoSizeCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath, I try to [cell.images addObject:imageName], but on AutoSizeCell.m, I try to NSLog self.images.count, it is zero

Comment: Your code looks rather incomplete. You pass a string to where an array of images seems to be expected. And then those images are not processed at all. Anyhow, your question is off-topic since it's of type "help me debugging my code".

Comment: Is the issue passing the array of images, or laying them out in the cell? Depending on how the grid of images flows that may actually be a non-trivial problem. Can I see `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in your tableview controller? That's where you can configure title, content, and images.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to override `-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder` instead of `init`.

Alternatively, don't do either of these things. Get rid of the init entirely and do this.

`cell.images = [self getImagesAtIndexPath:indexPath]`

Less code, less relying on cell state. And I'm pretty sure always adding images is going to cause issues when the cell gets reused unless you override `prepareForReuse`. Just setting the whole array is easier.